# Python multiprocessing queue makes code hang with large data

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, large-data

I'm using python's multiprocessing to analyse some large texts. After some days trying to figure out why my code was hanging (i.e. the processes didn't end), I was able to recreate the problem with the following simple code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

for y in range(65500, 65600):
    print(y)

    def func(output):

         output.put("a"*y)

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        output = mp.Queue()

        process = mp.Process(target = func, args = (output,))

        process.start()

        process.join()
```

As you can see, if the item to put in the queue gets too large, the process just hangs.
It doesn't freeze, if I write more code after `output.put()` it will run, but still, the process never stops.

This starts happening when the string gets to 65500 chars, depending on your interpreter it may vary.

I was aware that `mp.Queue` has a `maxsize` argument, but doing some search I found out it is about the Queue's size in number of items, not the size of the items themselves.

Is there a way around this?
The data I need to put inside the Queue in my original code is very very large...

Comment: Can you use file streams instead of strings? then you could operate on part of the data, leaving the rest on disk.

Comment: @steviestickman Actually I'm only using strings for this example. My original code uses a custom class I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queue fills up with no consumer to empty it.

From the definition of [`Queue.put`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.put):

> If the optional argument block is True (the default) and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until a free slot is available.

Assuming there is no deadlock possible between producer and consumer (and assuming your original code does have a consumer, since your sample doesn't), eventually the producers should be unlocked and terminate. Check the code of your consumer (or add it to the question, so we an have a look)

---

## Update

> This is not the problem, because queue has not been given a maxsize so put should succeed until you run out of memory.

This is not the behavior of Queue. As elaborated in this [ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue8426), the part blocking here is not the queue itself, but the underlying pipe. From the linked resource (inserts between "[]" are mine):

> A queue works like this:
>   - when you call queue.put(data), the data is added to a deque, which can grow and shrink forever
>   - then a thread pops elements from the deque, and sends them so that the other process can receive them through a pipe or a Unix socket (created via socketpair). But, and that's the important point, both pipes and unix sockets have a limited capacity (used to be 4k - pagesize - on older Linux kernels for pipes, now it's 64k, and between 64k-120k for unix sockets, depending on tunable systcls).
>   - when you do queue.get(), you just do a read on the pipe/socket
>
> [..] when size [becomes too big] the writing thread blocks on the write syscall.
>   And since a join is performed before dequeing the item [note: that's your `process.join`], you just deadlock, since the join waits for the sending thread to complete, and the write can't complete since the pipe/socket is full!
>   If you dequeue the item before waiting the submitter process, everything works fine.

---

## Update 2

> I understand. But I don't actually have a consumer (if it is what I'm thinking it is), I will only get the results from the queue when process has finished putting it into the queue.

Yeah, this is the problem. The `multiprocessing.Queue` is not a storage container. You should use it exclusively for passing data between "producers" (the processes that generate data that enters the queue) and "consumers (the processes that "use" that data). As you now know, leaving the data there is a bad idea.

> How can I get an item from the queue if I cannot even put it there first?

`put` and `get` hide away the problem of putting together the data if it fills up the pipe, so you only need to set up a loop in your "main" process to `get` items out of the queue and, for example, append them to a list. The list is in the memory space of the main process and does not clog the pipe.

Comment: This is not the problem, because `queue` has not been given a maxsize so put should succeed until you run out of memory.

Comment: I understand. But I don't actually have a consumer (if it is what I'm thinking it is), I will only get the results from the queue when `process` has finished putting it into the queue. How can I get an item from the queue if I cannot even put it there first?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not putting a lot of items until the pipe gets full, just one of my items is enough for filling it. You can run the code without the `for` loop, with `y = 65600`, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Wow, I made a test and actually I can `get` the item before it finishes the `put` method. Interesting...
I will see if it works for my original code. Thanks guys!

Comment: Indeed. As I expanded over in the second update, `put` and `get` take care of hiding away the object reconstruction if you block half-way through. You just need to get the data out of the queue.

Comment: Got it, now I have a consumer loop in the main process and it is working flawlessly.

Comment: As you suggested, I used the consumer BETWEEN start and join at the main process and it worked. Also, using mp.Manager().Queue() worked anyway, but probably you get the overhead of using a Manager().