# Is mp.Queue that limited in memory?

Tags: asynchronous, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing, batch-normalization

So, I've impemented my synchronous batch normalization layer. I've tried to test it by running on differenet set of parameters by this way: each mp.Process runs a function, which makes forward and backward passes and store output and grad values in a common mp.Queue ( `queue.put((out.detach().numpy(), grad.detach().numpy()))` ). If my params are batch_size=32 and num_features=128, it works fine. But if I increase num_features to 256, this stops working.

```
process 0 started
All processes started
forward done
backward done
sync processor must end
```

The function, which is running in each process, reaches the last print, but does not exit the function, so `joins` do not pass in main function.

So, as I understand, mp.queue do not let the 'parallel' function reach its end

I've tried to put `(1,1)` in queue instead of arrays and it worked. So the problem is in size of objects I put in queue. Is 256 * 32 too much? What is the memory limit of objects I can put in? Didn't find it in documentation.

Or this is not the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out.

Prevously my main function was like this:

```
processes = []
q = mp.Queue()
for rank, mini_batch in enumerate(mini_batches):
    p = Process(target=sync_processor, args=(mini_batch, sync_bn, rank, q, num_workers, imitate_to, port))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
    
out = []
grad = []

for _ in range(q.qsize()):
    elem = q.get()
    out.append(torch.tensor(elem[0]))
    grad.append(torch.tensor(elem[1]))
```

So I assumed, that my processes would fill up the queue, then I finish them and get data from queue in my main process. But after I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951832/python-multiprocessing-queue-makes-code-hang-with-large-data) now I understand (well, I hope I do), mp.queue needs to have a 'consumer' process. So I need to get data from queue before I finish all the processes. Now code looks like this and it works:

```
processes = []
q = mp.Queue()

for rank, mini_batch in enumerate(mini_batches):
    p = Process(target=sync_processor, args=(mini_batch, sync_bn, rank, q, num_workers, imitate_to, port))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
    
out = []
grad = []
    

for _ in range(num_workers):
    elem = q.get()
    out.append(torch.tensor(elem[0]))
    grad.append(torch.tensor(elem[1]))
        
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```